# FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:21 Wrong arguments 'stock_price_high':

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions, hiveql

I am new to Hive and I am trying to create and use a UDF in the Hive command line.

I created a Java code to calculate covariance of stocks based on sample NYSE data set. Below is the code in Java:

```
package udf;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;

public class CoVariance extends UDF {
    public Double covariance (Double stockpricex, Double stockpricey, Double avgstockpricex, Double avgstockpricey, int tuplecount) {

        if (stockpricex == null|| stockpricey == null || avgstockpricex == null || avgstockpricey == null || tuplecount == 0 ) {
        return null;
        } //check for invalid parameters

        Double covar = ((stockpricex-avgstockpricex)*(stockpricey-avgstockpricey)/(tuplecount - 1));

        return covar.doubleValue();     
    } // return the final co-variance of the stocks

} // end of class
```

After adding the jar file to hive shell, I created a tempoarary function called 'cv' and passed the parameters.

```
select stock_symbol, cv(stock_price_high, stock_price_low, avg(stock_price_high), avg(stock_price_low), count(stock_price_high)) from nyse group by stock_symbol, stock_price_high, stock_price_low;
```

I am getting below error:

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:21 Wrong arguments
>   'stock_price_high': No matching method for class udf.CoVariance with
>   (double, double, double, double, bigint). Possible choices:

What is going wrong here? Your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear how you registered the UDF, but the JavaDoc says this

> Requirements for all classes extending this UDF are:
>   - Implement one or more methods named `evaluate` which will be called by Hive

Your method `covariance` should be renamed to `evaluate`

And the `int tuplecount` should be `long` or `BigInteger`, according to the Hive error

Comment: https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r1.2.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec/UDF.html

Comment: There's also lots of blogs on Java UDFs. All I've seen mentioned that method

Comment: Thanks I will go through that link and will try to find blogs on UDFs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing that out, I thought we can define our own functions, but it seems we have to use that predefined function. If you can refer the JavaDoc help page that you are referring, that will really help.

Based on your suggestions, I made the below change to the code, and I can now cal this UDF from Hive Shell. But the result it is returning is Infinity for the calculation.

I tried changing the data type for 'tuplecount' to long and double, its still causing the same problem.

> QXM   QTM 2   Infinity

```
package customudf;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;


public class CoVariance extends UDF {
    public Double evaluate (double stockpricex, double stockpricey, double avgstockpricex, double avgstockpricey, double tuplecount) {

        Double result = null;

        if (stockpricex == 0|| stockpricey == 0 || avgstockpricex == 0 || avgstockpricey == 0 || tuplecount == 0 ) {
        return null;
        } //check for invalid parameters

        else {
        tuplecount --;  

        result = ((stockpricex-avgstockpricex)*(stockpricey-avgstockpricey)/(tuplecount));

        return result.doubleValue();

        }
    } // return the final co-variance of the stocks

} // end of class
```

Comment: Any suggestions?